# Validation of html before the visualization in a spreadsheet

Tags: html, validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I receive that error during the visualization of the email-html body in a spreadsheet.

> Script or content HTML not valid: HtmlOutput:11+28 - 45: malformed url 02-64484862 HtmlOutput:60+14 - 32: malformed url 051%20256011 HtmlOutput:60+102 - 120: malformed url 051%20256041 HtmlOutput:93+14 - 43: malformed url %2B%2B39%20051%20256011 HtmlOutput:94+13 - 42: malformed url %2B%2B39%20051%20256041. (line 12)

In my spreadsheet there are cells whose comment is the body of an email, and i want to visualize the email body in a spreadsheet.

Here is the code that I use.

```
var indiceRigaPerCuiVisualizzareEmail=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getRowIndex();
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(indiceRigaPerCuiVisualizzareEmail, 4).getComment()));
```

The problem I think is the sanitization that is done by Caja.
So how i can handle the case that an email contains invalid/unsafe content for Caja sanitization? If the original content of the e-mail can't be visualized, there is a workaround to visualize only the simple text of the email without HTML tags?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
HtmlService.createHtmlOutput().appendUntrusted(yourContent)
```

for first visualization. You should then see which tags need to be corrected.

Answer (score 0):

If we have some notes with valid HTML and others with invalid HTML we might use `try..catch` together with `HtmlOutput.appendUnstrusted()`. The tricky part is that `HtmlService` methods modifies the `HttpOutput` even if there is an error. `HttpOutput.append(content)` adds the content before the "malformation", considering this, in the following example I'm comparing the lengths of the `HttpOutput` content and the note content, if they aren't the same, then, first clear the `HttpOutput` in order to remove the "malformation", then `HttpOutput.appendUntrusted` is used to add the comment.

Note: Nowadays the `Range.getComment()` method is deprecated, but let say that `Range.getNote()` is used  instead.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const row = sheet.getActiveCell().getRow();
  const spreadsheet = sheet.getParent();
  const range = sheet.getRange(row, 4);
  const comment = range.getNote();
  const htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput();
  
  try{
    htmlOutput.append(comment); 
  } catch(error){

  }

  if( htmlOutput.getContent().length < comment.length){
    htmlOutput.clear();
    htmlOutput.append('<pre>');
    htmlOutput.appendUntrusted(comment);
    htmlOutput.append('</pre>');
  }
  
  spreadsheet.show(htmlOutput);
  
}
```

If you need help to find error, the [W3C Markup Validation Service](https://validator.w3.org/) might help.

Related

- [Google Apps Script: how to adding a second comment to the first without using getComment() method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20302532/1595451)