# Google Apps Script: how to adding a second comment to the first without using getComment() method

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I use this code to write a comment in a cell of my spreadsheet:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var currentRow = sheet.getActiveSelection().getRowIndex();
  var firstCell = sheet.getRange("A"+currentRow);
  firstCell.setComment(docName);
```

But I have this problem: when I put use a second time the same row and put a second comment the first comment is gone (replaced by the second comment). I know I can solve it with the deprecated method `getComment()`of Class Range.  Are there an alternative tho `getComment()` deprecated method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setComment()` is also deprecated, you should use [setNote()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setNote%28String%29) and [getNote()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getNote%28%29) instead

Comment: Serge, by chance your last name Brin? =) You know all about GAS. You must be a googler!

Comment: Serge indeed :-)  nope, not a Googler and certainly not knowing everything!!! :-)   But thanks for the compliment ^^ I'm working on it...